# Packages installed with pip not working in PyCharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I want to install matplotlib (and other packages) using pip, and every tutorial I found uses this command in the terminal:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

The command prompt returns

```
"Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable"
```

as well as a few lines saying the requirement is already satisfied.

When trying to import matplotlib in PyCharm, it returns a ModuleNotFoundError, but it works in IDLE.

I reinstalled Python312 and PyCharm, and tried the command in cmd several times.

I don't know where pip is supposed to install packages, but the only place where I found matplotlib on my computer is in python's folder of AppData\Local\ .

I'm using Windows 10 and python 3.12.

Comment: i think your pycharm cannot find you python path

Comment: [check this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-existing-interpreter)
check this

Comment: This worked thanks.